# no such method 'getTab' for tabs widget instance in jquery ui 1.12.1 version

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-plugins

I am upgrading jQuery UI in my project from 1.9 to 1.12. I am creating tabs. But, it is giving 'no such method 'getTab' for tabs widget instance'

```
var tab =  $('#' + this.id).tabs('getTab', '#' + this.id )//working in jQuery UI 1.9 but giving error in 1.12.
```

I am not sure how to call `gettab()` method in latest jquery ui version. Please help

Comment: This is the code of gettab method also that I found in other file. 
 getTab: function (name) {
  var idx = this.indexOf(name);
  if (idx >= 0) {
  return this._ui(this.anchors[idx], this.panels[idx]);
 }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When I review the Docs for jQuery UI 1.9 and 1.12, there is no reference to `getTab`. Are you using an extra library or a Custom widget? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It might also be best to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour